# How to set the value of input textfield with the character "

Tags: html

I tried the following code, but it did not work to set the input field to have the value `"` . Does anyone have any idea how to set it.

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" value="\""><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"` (Double Quote) is not a ASCII Character. Browser can not render an Non-ASCII Character (if you have to press any key or any combination of keys except shift key to build a character). 
Now you have to use HTML Character Entity Name  `&quot;` or Entities Number `&#34;` or Entity Construct Encode `&#x00022;` for the Double Quote character. Please see the following code:

```html
<!-- Entity Name -->
<input type="text" name="fname" value="&quot;"><br>
<!-- Entity Number -->
<input type="text" name="fname" value="&#34;"><br>
<!-- Entity Construct Encode -->
<input type="text" name="fname" value="&#x00022;">
```

[More about HTML Character Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).
[Complete cheat-sheet of HTML Character Entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Answer (score 4):

use `&quot;` HTML designed work like this.

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" value="&quot;">
```